# Skobbler annotation with button

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, skmaps

I am creating a Skobbler Annotation as follows:

```
markerCoords = mapView.pointToCoordinate(skScreenPoint); //gives us the coordinate

SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(11);
SKAnnotationView view = new SKAnnotationView();

View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.annotation_marker, null, false);
v.findViewById(R.id.btn_destination).setOnClickListener(destListener);
v.findViewById(R.id.btn_origin).setOnClickListener(originListener);
view.setView(v);

annotation.setAnnotationView(view);
annotation.setLocation(mapView.pointToCoordinate(skScreenPoint));
annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(1);

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_POP_OUT);
```

The view `R.layout.annotation_marker` contains a couple of buttons, but I can't tap/click them. My click goes through the annotation and hits the map instead (I've detected it). I've tried using requestFocus() on the view when I inflate it, but that has no effect. I also have `android:clickable='true'` in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Origin"
         android:id="@+id/btn_origin"
         android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:clickable="true"/>

    <Button
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:text="Destination"
         android:id="@+id/btn_destination" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**How do I get the click event to hit the buttons instead of the underlying map?**

Comment: You need to set the center point of the image- tapping on an annotation will depend on this value.

Comment: @SylviA What is the center point of the image, and how do I set this value? And what image are you talking about? Thanks

Comment: I think I've misunderstood. I was thinking about this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589941/skobbler-onannotationselected-not-called-when-i-set-my-own-annotations

Comment: This question was reported to the Scout dev team.

Comment: @SylviA Many thanks, I hope to hear from them soon. I've had to workaround it at the moment using several different annotations acting as the different buttons, and using the onAnnotationSelected callback.

Comment: @SylviA Has there been any further development on this? Thanks

Comment: still waiting for a feedback

Answer (score 2):

Since the onClick event doesn’t happen, the solution in order to enable events on different views situated on map is incorporating them in different annotations using annotationViews and the execute actions on the onAnnotationSelected callback(so there should be one view per annotation).

In order to make an event trigger in a natural manner a corresponding offset must be set to the annotation so as the onAnnotationSelected callback to be triggered when the actual view is clicked, not the extension of the annotation.

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(SKMapViewHolder mapHolder) { 
…. 
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(137);
SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bug_2_btn_layout,null,false);
annotationView.setView(v);
annotation.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(52.520008,13.404954));
annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(1); 


double viewToLayoutRatio = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.originBtn_width)/getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.annotationLayout_width);
annotation.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint((float) (annotation.getOffset().getX()-(viewToLayoutRatio*getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.originBtn_width))), (float) (annotation.getOffset().getY()+(viewToLayoutRatio/3)*getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.originBtn_width)))); 

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_POP_OUT); 
… 
} 

@Override
public void onAnnotationSelected(final SKAnnotation annotation) { 
switch (annotation.getUniqueID()) { 
… 
case 137:
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Annotation was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bug_2_btn_layout,null,false);
 originClicked(v);
 break;
 }
}
```